# Bredis 0.07 - Sending HMSET command with multiple entries

Tags: c++, redis

Trying to figure out the best way to send a HMSET command with a large (possibly 2000 pairs).

What im currently doing is creating a single string for each chunk of pairs, set up as 'key "value"'.  Is this the best way, or each as a param to the single_command_t, or as a iterator, with the command, key, and all value pairs after? @Ivan Baidakou

```cpp
 modbusResponseCommands.emplace_back(bredis::single_command_t("MULTI"));
...
for (int j = 0; j < data._readCoilsResponses.size(); ++j) {
   int regId = data._readCoilsResponses[j].first;
   int regValue = data._readCoilsResponses[j].second;

   dataStr += std::to_string(regId) + '"';
   dataStr += std::to_string(regValue) + '"';
   dataStr += " ";
   if (j != 0 && j % 2000 == 0) {
        modbusResponseCommands.emplace_back(
            bredis::single_command_t(
                "HMSET",
                _key + ":rcres:unitId:" + std::to_string(unit.first),
                dataStr
            )
        );
        dataStr = "";
    }
}
modbusResponseCommands.emplace_back(
    bredis::single_command_t(
        "HMSET",
        _key + ":rcres:unitId:" + std::to_string(unit.first),
        dataStr
    )
);
...
modbusResponseCommands.emplace_back(bredis::single_command_t("EXEC"));
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `MULTI`, as [HMSET](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) already supports multiple key/values at once.

```
using pair_t = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using holder_t = std::vector<pair_t>;
holder_t holder;
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> _readCoilsResponses;
r::single_command_t cmd{"HMSET"};
for (int j = 0; j < _readCoilsResponses.size(); ++j) {
   int regId = _readCoilsResponses[j].first;
   int regValue = _readCoilsResponses[j].second;
   holder.emplace_back(std::to_string(regId), std::to_string(regValue));
   auto& last_pair = holder.back();
   cmd.arguments.emplace_back(last_pair.first);
   cmd.arguments.emplace_back(last_pair.second);
}
```

Basically `MULTI` should have the same effect as `HMSET` with all arguments, but it will put slightly more load on redis-server.

You can omit `MULTI` and just send a list of `HMSET` commands, which will be executed non-atomically, but that's way you'll give some breath for redis-server; but that should matter if you send megabytes of data.